# impossible to create replica instance

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, replication

I want to create a read replicat for ideally for a mysql server (on aws rds). I want not able to do that so I followed this example (git clone https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-rds.git) to make a read replica for a postgresql server.
I took the example as it is and made my terraform apply.
the master DB is created correctly, however, when trying to create the replicated server, I get this error message :

```
│ Error: Error creating DB Instance: InvalidDBInstanceState: Automated backups are not enabled for this database instance. To enable automated backups, use ModifyDBInstance to set the backup retention period to a non-zero value.
│       status code: 400, request id: 7fe93381-bfbe-4ddb-9f35-aa6ba7591e16
```

Can you help me to run the default example at least. Then I will have to replace the postgresql tp mysql engine.
Regards
Adel

Comment: Is the solution in the error message not possible or not functioning as expected?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to enable automated backup first like this:

```
resource "aws_db_instance_automated_backups_replication" "main_instance_bacup" {
  source_db_instance_arn = aws_db_instance.main_instance.arn

  retention_period       = 3 
}
```

then create a new resource

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "read_replica" {
// necessary configs
source_db_instance_identifier = aws_db_instance.main_instance.id

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you need to enable automated backups. To do it via terraform you need to pass this parameter:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#backup_retention_period